# Gas Water Boiler overheats only when zone3 activated

Tags: boiler, water-circulating-heating

Hello I am having a problem with my gas hot water boiler heating up my Zone3 or 2nd floor. When running the boiler with Zones1 and Zones2 (basement and 1st flr) at high water heat 180F - 220F, everyworks fine. But when running the Boiler just to heat Zone3 at high or medium temp (180F and up) it starts banging and if not stopped and if the temperature isn't lowered , the overflow valve activates releasing hot steam and boiling water. Strangely running Zone3 on low temp under 150F, the Boiler runs fine, but it does little to warm up my second floor at under 150F.

Also noticed that when all three zones are running I am able to up the temperature to 160F without the boiler overheating.

Comment: Probably zone 3 is airlocked, at least paritially, and needs to have the air bled out of it. Hopefully it has air bleeders installed at the high points of the loop so that's not a difficult task.

Comment: Thank you, but it looks like I have a closed loop copper water pipe heat system, the only bleeder I see by the furnace. I've drained the water out of the system and back in and opened and closed the single air valve I see.

I also noticed that my pressure guage is off. When I drained the system it goes down to 100, when I heat fill it with cold water it goes up to 120, and when I heat the water to apx 160F it goes up to 140-150 pressure, if I heat the water any higher, the pressure valve goes off and sprays steam over my basement.